# left join take very long

Tags: sql

I have two tables (ProdOrders and PreCalcTime)
Now I want to check if all the ProdOrders do have a associated PreCalcTime
Each ProdOrder has a drawingnumber and each PreCalcTime is based on this drawing number
So I made the following query:

```
select Distinct PO.TEKNR from ProdOrders PO
left join PreCalcTime PCT on PO.drawingnr = PCT.Drawingnr
where V.Time is NULL
```

This query works very well but takes a very long time with ~15000 production orders (having ~550 distincted drawingnumbers)

of course I can try to optimize using some filtering but are there also other options like "not in select" or other techniques to speedup this query

Looking forward to your ideas

Comment: What is `V` in the `V.Time`?

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: You can speed up things a little by removing `DISTINCT` and adding `GROUP BY PO.TEKNR`. Anyway are `PO.drawingnr` and `PCT.Drawingnr` indexed?

Comment: @Mike: replacing a `distinct` with a `group by`will not make a difference with any modern optimizer.

Comment: Why the outer join at all? If you only want (distinct) rows from `prodorders` a sub-query (either with `IN` or `EXISTS`) is a much better choice

Comment: That query is invalid and wont even execute.

Comment: Hi there, The V should be PCT (I translated the tablenames to english ;-) ), furthermore I'm using Firebird and no the PO.drawingnr and PCT.Drawingnr are not indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `V.Time` is a bug and you just want to find `ProdOrders` that do not have `Drawingnr` in `PreCalcTime`. Use `NOT EXISTS` it is the most efficient way in many database systems ([Postgres](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/), [Oracle](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/), [SQL Server](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)).

```
select Distinct PO.TEKNR 
from ProdOrders PO
where not exists (
   select 1
   from PreCalcTime PCT 
   where PO.drawingnr = PCT.Drawingnr
)
```

the distinct might not be necessary in this solution since the JOIN is not there.

Comment: Yes the V.Time is a bug. Thanks for your solution is already much faster

Answer (score 0):

I now found another possibilty.
If I use only the distincted drawingnumbers from the ProdOrder table I save a lot of lookups. Based on that I made a subquery in my from statement.
In this way it runs really fast

```
select DPO.DrawNr from 
(select distinct PO.drawingnr DrawNr from ProdOrders PO) DPO
left join PreCalcTime PCT on DPO.DrawNr = PCT.drawingnr
where  PCT.Time is NULL
```

The results are the same but the big question is now is this a correct way